# How to reset password in postgresql (psql) for particular role in case when I list the role name it is not exist?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have installed PostgreSQL for a long time but just currently learning it.

---

Here is what happened if I **run `psql`** in the command prompt

> ```
> C:\Users\VandaRsq>psql 
> Password for user Vanda Rashq:
> ```

Since I forgot the password for the `Vanda Rashq` role but I remember for the `postgres` role, I **run `psql -U postgres`**.

---

I tried to **list the role by using `du`** command and the result is this:
[image: du]

I also tried **using `SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles`** command and yield:

[image: select]

---

I have tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-reset-password/) and do `ALTER USER "Vanda Rashq" WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';` but it returns `ERROR: role "Vanda Rashq" does not exist`

**My question** is, does the "Vanda Rashq" role actually still exist? If yes, how to reset (change) the password in case I forgot the password? If not, how to change the default role when running `psql` to `postgres` role

---

**Notes:** I have tried to uninstall the PostgreSQL and remove all of the directories but when I try to run `psql`, it still ask `Password for user Vanda Rashq`

Answer (score 0):

If the user you're looking for is not listed after calling `\du` in `psql` then the user does not exist in the database.

Btw, you could also use a select to retrieve information about database users: `select * from pg_catalog.pg_user;`

**EDIT:**

Like @jjanes pointed out you get challenged for a password based on the `USER` configuration in your`pg_hba.conf` ([see docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)).

For authentication method `peer` it is stated:

> Obtain the client's operating system user name from the operating system and check if it matches the requested database user name.

Comment: If the pg_hba has a matching line for 'all' users which indicates use of a password, then non-existent users are still challenged for a password.  That way attackers can't enumerate which users exist just by inspecting the error message.